# Easier way to .setValue for .getRange without loosing formulas in other cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have the following code working. However, there is likely a much easier method to accomplish it. I have a spreadsheet that I added a "Reset button" that resets the values of some cells back to default. The problem I ran into was that the other cells within my range that I was not wanting to reset and that contained a formula, lost their formula.
So I added to my values to include reposting those formulas as well. You can see where I added this section based on the comments in my script. Which now makes my code quite long.
Any recommendations for a shorter code version?

[image: Screenshot]
To help clarify. I only want to reset the ranges within the green squares. My code down to //Dates Formulas will delete all formulas. So I added from //Dates Formulas on down to write in the formulas in the red circled ranges.

I am thinking I should be able to do something with Named Ranges but I have not been able to find a code example online.

```
function ResetPesoTags() {
var range = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet-id-#").getSheetByName("PesosTagsPrint").getRange("A1:M28");
var values = range.getValues();
//values = [1st #] is row (1=0 2=1) [2nd #] is column (A=0 B=1)
//CA Kitchen
values[2][1] = "3";
values[3][1] = "3";
values[4][1] = "5";
values[5][1] = "5";
values[6][1] = "5";
values[7][1] = "2";
values[8][1] = "4";
values[9][1] = "2";
values[10][1] = "6";
values[11][1] = "0";
//LA Kitchen
values[2][5] = "3";
values[3][5] = "3";
values[4][5] = "5";
values[5][5] = "5";
values[6][5] = "5";
values[7][5] = "2";
values[8][5] = "4";
values[9][5] = "2";
values[10][5] = "6";
values[11][5] = "0";
//Maintenance
values[2][9] = "7";
values[3][9] = "4";
values[4][9] = "5";
values[5][9] = "2";
values[6][9] = "5";
values[7][9] = "0";
values[8][9] = "0";
//CA Kitchen
values[18][1] = "14";
values[19][1] = "20";
values[20][1] = "21";
values[21][1] = "5";
values[22][1] = "6";
values[23][1] = "1";
values[24][1] = "4";
//values[25][1] = "0";
//values[26][1] = "0";
//values[27][1] = "0";
//LA Student
values[18][5] = "14";
values[19][5] = "20";
values[20][5] = "21";
values[21][5] = "5";
values[22][5] = "6";
values[23][5] = "1";
values[24][5] = "4";
//values[25][5] = "0";
//values[26][5] = "0";
//values[27][5] = "0";
//Other
values[17][9] = "0";
values[18][9] = "0";
values[19][9] = "0";
values[20][9] = "0";
values[21][9] = "0";
values[22][9] = "0";
values[23][9] = "0";
values[24][9] = "0";

//From here down it is rewriting the formulas that get lost
//Dates Formulas
values[0][0] = "=$M$2";
values[0][4] = "=$M$2";
values[0][8] = "=$M$2";
values[16][0] = "=$M$2";
values[16][4] = "=$M$2";
values[15][8] = "=$M$2";
//CA Kitchen Formulas
values[2][2] = "=A3*B3";
values[3][2] = "=A4*B4";
values[4][2] = "=A5*B5";
values[5][2] = "=A6*B6";
values[6][2] = "=A7*B7";
values[7][2] = "=A8*B8";
values[8][2] = "=A9*B9";
values[9][2] = "=A10*B10";
values[10][2] = "=A11*B11";
values[11][2] = "=A12*B12";
values[12][2] = "=SUM(C3:C12)";
//LA Kitchen Formulas
values[2][6] = "=E3*F3";
values[3][6] = "=E4*F4";
values[4][6] = "=E5*F5";
values[5][6] = "=E6*F6";
values[6][6] = "=E7*F7";
values[7][6] = "=E8*F8";
values[8][6] = "=E9*F9";
values[9][6] = "=E10*F10";
values[10][6] = "=E11*F11";
values[11][6] = "=E12*F12";
values[12][6] = "=SUM(G3:G12)";
//Maintenance Formulas
values[2][10] = "=I3*J3";
values[3][10] = "=I3*J3";
values[4][10] = "=I3*J3";
values[5][10] = "=I3*J3";
values[6][10] = "=I3*J3";
values[7][10] = "=I3*J3";
values[8][10] = "=I3*J3";
values[9][10] = "=SUM(K3:K9)";
//CA Student Formulas
values[18][2] = "=A19*B19";
values[19][2] = "=A20*B20";
values[20][2] = "=A21*B21";
values[21][2] = "=A22*B22";
values[22][2] = "=A23*B23";
values[23][2] = "=A24*B24";
values[24][2] = "=A25*B25";
values[25][2] = "=SUM(C19:C25)";
//LA Student Formulas
values[18][6] = "=E19*F19";
values[19][6] = "=E20*F20";
values[20][6] = "=E21*F21";
values[21][6] = "=E22*F22";
values[22][6] = "=E23*F23";
values[23][6] = "=E24*F24";
values[24][6] = "=E25*F25";
values[25][6] = "=SUM(G19:G25)";
//Other Formulas
values[17][10] = "=I18*J18";
values[18][10] = "=I19*J19";
values[19][10] = "=I20*J20";
values[20][10] = "=I21*J21";
values[21][10] = "=I22*J22";
values[22][10] = "=I23*J23";
values[23][10] = "=I24*J24";
values[24][10] = "=I25*J25";
values[25][10] = "=SUM(K18:K25)";
range.setValues(values);
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the situation of `The problem I ran into was that the other cells within my range that I was not resetting and that contained a formula, those cells lost their formula.`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail flow for replicating the issue?

Comment: Sorry for the poor explanation, I added a screenshot which I hope helps.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor skill. Unfortunately, from your updated question, I cannot still replicate your situation. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail flow for replicating the issue? By the way, in your sample image, when `RESET` button is clicked, the function of `ResetPesoTags()` is run?

Comment: And also, I cannot understand about `To help clarify. I only want to reset the ranges within the green squares. My code down to //Dates Formulas will delete all formulas. So I added from //Dates Formulas on down to write in the formulas in the red circled ranges.`. I think that your script put the values of "green squares" and also, put the formulas of the red circle. So I cannot understand about your goal. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Our school uses this spreadsheet each week to put together bags of pesos. They print this sheet of tags and cut them apart so they can document what is in the bags. If we have sufficient quantities of each denomination on hand, they can just print the tags and put together the bags. Otherwise they need to adjust the #s (in the green squares) to match what # of each denomination is in the bag. The RESET runs the script and resets the #s (in the green boxes) back to the default settings. This way they do not need to do it manually.

Comment: On the spreadsheet, the green square ranges contain numbers and I want a script that sets those values back to "default".                                                                                              The ranges circled in red contain formulas to sum-up the $ values or to copy the date (from M2). These formulas were lost when I ran the script. So to fix that I added more to my script so that the script rewrote the formulas to those cells.

Comment: So.. my question is, how can I set the values of the green-boxed ranges without overwriting the values outside of the green-boxed ranges?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you expect, I apologize. At that time, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

> So.. my question is, how can I set the values of the green-boxed ranges without overwriting the values outside of the green-boxed ranges?

- In your sample situation, you want to put the values to the specific ranges of "B3:B12", "F3:F12", "J3:J9", "F19:F25" and "J18:J25".

In this case, I would like to use the method of "spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate" in Sheets API. When Sheets API is used, the values can be put to the specific ranges by one API call.

When the values of "B3:B12", "F3:F12", "J3:J9", "F19:F25" and "J18:J25" in your sample image are used, the sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheet name.
  // Please set the range and the values you want to put as JSON object.
  const obj = {
    "B3:B12": [3,3,5,5,5,2,4,2,6,0],
    "F3:F12": [3,3,5,5,5,2,4,2,6,0],
    "J3:J9": [7,4,5,2,5,0,0],
    "F19:F25": [14,20,21,5,6,1,4],
    "J18:J25": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  };

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const data = Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => ({range: `'${sheetName}'!${k}`, values: v.map(e => [e]), majorDimension: "ROWS"}));
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({data: data, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"}, ss.getId());
}
```

- `obj` is used for putting values to the specific ranges.
- If you want to change the values of `obj`, please modify above script.
- In this case, `majorDimension: "ROWS"` might not be required to be used.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

Comment: THANKS!  I had started with some code like this but could not figure it out. 1. I was missing the step of enabling the Sheets API 2. I was thinking I needed to replace "USER_ENTERED" and I had no clue what to put in there. Your script works and is so much simpler to maintain if the cells/values change.

Comment: @Iowa Boy Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `I was missing the step of enabling the Sheets API`, you can confirm it at [this official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). About `I was thinking I needed to replace "USER_ENTERED" and I had no clue what to put in there.`, you can confirm it at [this official document](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption). From your situation, I thought that `USER_ENTERED` might be suitable.